# Can't Embed Vue Component into an md-app using Vue Material

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-material

I have the following...

PageHeader.vue

```
<template>
  <span> ${message} </span>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
      data: function(){
        return {message: "asdsad" };
      }
    }
</script>
```

app.vue

```
<template>
<jg-header></jg-header>  
</template>
<script>
  import PageHeader from "./PageHeader.vue"
  export default{
    components: {
      "jg-header": PageHeader
    }
  }
</script>
```

This works great so I want to convert it to using Vue Material so I change app.vue to this...

```
<template>
  <md-app> <jg-header></jg-header> </md-app>  
</template>
<script>
  import PageHeader from "./PageHeader.vue"
  export default{
    components: {
      "jg-header": PageHeader
    }
  }
</script>
```

It seems to create and render the Vue material component, however, the custom component doesn't show up anywhere. How do I get the Vue component to actually render inside the md-app

## Update

Since there was some confusion, I create the Vue app I do call Vue.use (hence why it renders)

```
Vue.use(VueMaterial);
new Vue(App).$mount("#my-id");
```

Comment: I also stated the vue material component rendered properly which is why I assumed it was obvious. It wouldn't render dom without being used. Sorry you got confused.

Comment: If the DOM is there, then the problem could be CSS, which would be solved by `import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'`. Are you importing it? (See how nothing is obvious?)

Comment: Yup again it isn't the styling it is the custom component not rendering. It is like when material is rendering it isn't rendering the non material components underneath it. I will try to make a plunker today

Comment: Here is the breaking example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoEEGE?editors=1010

Comment: It def looks like despite the docs saying md-toolbar is a alias for md-app-toolbar it isn't working right. So that is one issue, but still fails when I try to make it a component. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vREOYy?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<md-app>` has specific content elements. Wrap your content in `<md-app-content>`.

Instead of:

```
<template>
  <md-app> <jg-header></jg-header> </md-app>  
</template>
```

Do:

```
<template>
   <md-app>
      <md-app-content>
         <jg-header></jg-header>
      <md-app-content>
   </md-app>  
</template>
```

Or, with a toolbar:

```
<template>
   <md-app>
      <md-app-toolbar> ... </md-app-toolbar>
      <md-app-content>
         <jg-header></jg-header>
      <md-app-content>
   </md-app>  
</template>
```

Comment: Ill try but this won't work for my case because the template itself will contain a md-toolbar and should be ok to be directly under app according to their docs

Comment: * the template itself*, the template of your component will include the toolbar, is that it?

Comment: No the custom template will eventually, however, this didn't work even without that.

Comment: Again I will try to make a plunker later maybe then you will see what mean

Comment: I was assuming you were using a different template engine, but in the default one you do know it is `{{ message }}` not `${message}`, yes?

Comment: I think it is getting blocked at work I will look at it when I get home

Comment: As for the message I fixed that before too I just forgot to update. Still having the issue though and def not working with toolbar btw md-app-content == md-content

Comment: Oops I was commenting on the question not the answer ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166544/discussion-between-jackie-and-acdcjunior).

Answer (score -1):

> Try wrapping the tags inside template with a div :

```
<template>
  <div>
   <md-app> 
    <jg-header></jg-header>
   </md-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: No dice same outcome I see up to md-app-scroller then nothing inside it